# Приходит пустое письмо при повторном отправке на gmail

Tags: php

Когда я отправляю письмо повторно на почту mail или yandex, то письмо отправляется и оно не пустое, а когда отправляю на gmail, оно становится пустым, при повторном отправлении

```
if((isset($_POST['name-send']) && $_POST['name-send']!="") && (isset($_POST['tel-send']) && $_POST['tel-send']!="")){
$name = trim(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['name-send']))));
$tel =  trim(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['tel-send']))));

$to = "example@gmail.com";
$subject = "От поситителя сайта";
$text =  "Написал(а): $name\n Контактный телефон - $tel\n\n";

$header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";

$sending = mail($to, $subject, $text, $header);

if($sending) echo "Письмо отправлено. Ждите ответа";
}
?>
```

Comment: *при повторном отправлении* — т.е., при первом отправлении письмо приходит в нормальном виде? тогда зачем вы отсылаете его повторно?

Comment: отсылаем повторно для тех случаев, когда пользователь захочет отправить сообщение ещё раз, фишка в том , что если отправлять разные сообщения, то всё норм- письма не пустые, а если одинаковые - пустые. Я так понимаю это особенность gmail или я не прав?

Comment: пожалуйста, отразите всё это прямо в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не думаю что тут проблема в скрипте. Есть подозрение что все дело в специфике gmail - письма с одинаковыми данными (тема, отправитель и т.п.) отображаются в вебинтерфейсе в одно письмо (цепочка сообщений) - только может меняться число в скобках рядом с телом письма.